# jBPM : Not able to start business application in dev mode

Tags: docker, jbpm

I am running jBPM (v7.18) in docker on localhost using the following docker-compose configuration:

```
version: '2'

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:10.4
        volumes:
            - ./volumes/psql/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=jbpm
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=jbpm
        ports:
            - 5432:5432

    jbpm:
        image: jboss/jbpm-server-full
        environment:
            JBPM_DB_DRIVER: postgres
            JBPM_DB_HOST: postgres
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
            - 8001:8001
        volumes:
            - "/Users/guest/prac/jbpm/quickfox:/opt/jboss/quickfox"
        depends_on:
            - postgres
```

I generated the business application from https://start.jbpm.org/

I am starting the service of the business application in dev mode as follows.

```
./launch-dev.sh clean install
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/latest/jbpm-docs/html_single/index.html#_configure_business_application) ,

KIE server configuration needs to be as follows:

```
kieserver.serverId=business-application-service
kieserver.serverName=business-application-service
kieserver.location=http://localhost:8090/rest/server
kieserver.controllers=http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller
```

(which are the default settings in application-dev.properties)

But when I start the service it is not able to connect to business-central. I get the following logs

```
2019-05-01 11:56:50.789  INFO 47000 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.j.u.f.r.BootstrapFormRenderer    : Boostrap Form renderer templates loaded successfully.
2019-05-01 11:56:50.795  INFO 47000 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.j.u.f.r.PatternflyFormRenderer   : patternfly Form renderer templates loaded successfully.
2019-05-01 11:56:50.799  INFO 47000 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.j.u.f.r.PatternflyFormRenderer   : workbench Form renderer templates loaded successfully.
2019-05-01 11:56:50.801  INFO 47000 --- [           main] o.k.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl   : jBPM-UI KIE Server extension has been successfully registered as server extension
2019-05-01 11:56:50.802  INFO 47000 --- [           main] o.k.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl   : DMN KIE Server extension has been successfully registered as server extension
2019-05-01 11:56:50.806  INFO 47000 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.impl.policy.PolicyManager        : Registered KeepLatestContainerOnlyPolicy{interval=0 ms} policy under name KeepLatestOnly
2019-05-01 11:56:50.807  INFO 47000 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.impl.policy.PolicyManager        : Policy manager started successfully, activated policies are []
2019-05-01 11:56:50.817  WARN 47000 --- [           main] o.kie.server.common.KeyStoreHelperUtil   : Unable to load key store. Using password from configuration
2019-05-01 11:56:50.933  WARN 47000 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.i.c.DefaultRestControllerImpl    : Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/business-application-service-dev error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/business-application-service-dev response code 405
2019-05-01 11:56:50.933  WARN 47000 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.i.ControllerBasedStartupStrategy : Unable to connect to any controllers, delaying container installation until connection can be established
2019-05-01 11:56:50.934  WARN 47000 --- [ntrollerConnect] o.kie.server.common.KeyStoreHelperUtil   : Unable to load key store. Using password from configuration
2019-05-01 11:56:50.950  WARN 47000 --- [ntrollerConnect] o.k.s.s.i.c.DefaultRestControllerImpl    : Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/business-application-service-dev error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/business-application-service-dev response code 405
2019-05-01 11:56:51.009  INFO 47000 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.a.KieServerAutoConfiguration     : KieServer (id business-application-service-dev) started successfully
2019-05-01 11:56:51.339  INFO 47000 --- [           main] org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl       : Setting the server's publish address to be /
2019-05-01 11:56:51.652  INFO 47000 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
2019-05-01 11:56:51.658  INFO 47000 --- [           main] com.quickfox.service.Application         : Started Application in 13.158 seconds (JVM running for 13.969)
2019-05-01 11:57:00.954  WARN 47000 --- [ntrollerConnect] o.kie.server.common.KeyStoreHelperUtil   : Unable to load key store. Using password from configuration
2019-05-01 11:57:00.961  WARN 47000 --- [ntrollerConnect] o.k.s.s.i.c.DefaultRestControllerImpl    : Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/business-application-service-dev error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/business-application-service-dev response code 405
2019-05-01 11:57:10.963  WARN 47000 --- [ntrollerConnect] o.kie.server.common.KeyStoreHelperUtil   : Unable to load key store. Using password from configuration
2019-05-01 11:57:10.972  WARN 47000 --- [ntrollerConnect] o.k.s.s.i.c.DefaultRestControllerImpl    : Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/business-application-service-dev error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/controller/server/business-application-service-dev response code 405
```

But If I use the following configuration it works.

```
kieserver.serverId=business-application-service-dev
kieserver.serverName=business-application-service Dev
kieserver.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server
kieserver.controllers=http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller
```

Can someone tell me what is the reason for this behavior? Please correct me if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd set of URLs that you used are correct URLs. It seems like documentation needs to be corrected. "jbpm-console" end point were used in older versions.